# Calculating sum of the values in data frame by mapping the corresponding elements of a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, tuples, mapping

I have a data frame as shown here and below [![enter image description here][1]][1]

and I want to calculate the sum of values of the cells where the following conditions are met:

**Condition1**:LOC IN ('8','21') AND TYPE IN ('x','y','z')

**Condition2**:LOC IN ('30','16') AND TYPE IN ('x','y','z','q')

For example, I want to get the following results:

Condition1: 2+3+3+5+6+8=27
Condition2: 2+2+3+6+3+1+2+2=21

And here is the the example data frame as code:

```
data = {'LOC': [5, 8, 16, 21,30,35],
        'x': [5, 2, 3, 5,2,2],
        'y':[6,3,1,6,2,1],
        'z':[7,3,2,8,3,4],
        'q':[8,4,2,9,6,5],
        'p':[10,5,3,1,7,3]
       }
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition 1:

```py
df[df.LOC.isin([8,21])][['x','y','z']].sum().sum()
```

2:

```py
df[df.LOC.isin([30,16])][['x','y','z','q']].sum().sum()
```

Note that from `pandas>=2.0.0` `.sum().sum()` can be replaced by `.sum(axis=None)`

Edit: to answer your comment, what if a key is not in the dataframe. I would use an intersection then:

```py
df[df.LOC.isin([30,16])][df.columns.intersection(['x','y','z','q','h'])].sum().sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if another condition having an element that is not available in the data frame? For example, when I run the same code for Condition3: LOC IN ('30','16') AND TYPE IN ('x','y','z','q','h'). In this case code throws error with the "['h'] not in index" message since h is not in the data frame. What could be the way to ignore not found values in the index?

Comment: Check my comment for an answer